# What is Grails Build Config Transitive = false

Tags: grails, pom.xml, grails-plugin, buildconfig

I've noticed that in our build config there's a `transitive = false` in the plugins what is the meaning of this? what's the difference when doing an `excludes` i.e

`excludes 'code-coverage', 'maven-publisher', 'codenarc'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an explanation in [earlier documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.2.1/guide/conf.html):

> **Disabling transitive dependency resolution**
>
> By default, Grails will not only get the JARs and plugins that you
>   declare, but it will also get their transitive dependencies. This is
>   usually what you want, but there are occasions where you want a
>   dependency without all its baggage. In such cases, you can disable
>   transitive dependency resolution on a case-by-case basis:
>
> ```
> runtime('com.mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.16',
>         'net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:1.6.1') {
>     transitive = false
> }
>
> // Or
> runtime group:'com.mysql',
>         name:'mysql-connector-java',
>         version:'5.1.16',
>         transitive:false
> ```
>
> **Excluding specific transitive dependencies**
>
> A far more common scenario is where you want the transitive
>   dependencies, but some of them cause issues with your own dependencies
>   or are unnecessary. For example, many Apache projects have
>   'commons-logging' as a transitive dependency, but it shouldn't be
>   included in a Grails project (we use SLF4J). That's where the excludes
>   option comes in:
>
> ```
> runtime('com.mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.16',
>         'net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:1.6.1') {
>     excludes "xml-apis", "commons-logging"
> }
>
> // Or
> runtime(group:'com.mysql', name:'mysql-connector-java', version:'5.1.16') {
>     excludes([ group: 'xml-apis', name: 'xml-apis'],
>              [ group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' ],
>              [ name: 'commons-logging' ])
> ```
>
> As you can see, you can either exclude dependencies by their artifact
>   ID (also known as a module name) or any combination of group and
>   artifact IDs (if you use the Map notation). You may also come across
>   exclude as well, but that can only accept a single string or Map:
>
> ```
> runtime('com.mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.16',
>         'net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:1.6.1') {
>     exclude "xml-apis"
> }
> ```